# Best way to update checkbox prefefences

Tags: android, settings, sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

I was coding a clock for android. For it, i set a function which  updates screen 1 time each a second, so my program can consume a lot of resources, and my objective is to add a checkbox preference, consuming the less resources as I can.

Then, my question is: I have seen some ways to update preferences with `onSharedPreferenceChangeListener` for example... Which is the way which consumes less system resources? How should I implement it to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a `PreferenceActivity` you can implement the `OnPreferenceClickListener` set a listener on the checkbox then in your `onPreferenceClick` method with the key you set for the box and do what you need to do with it

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    if (preference.getKey().equals("schedulestart")) {
        showDialog(0);
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("schedulestop")) {
        showDialog(1);
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("priority")) {
        // Reset unread count when switching mailboxes. They might differ.
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("unreadcount", 0).commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! have I put this to the preference activity or to the main activity?

Comment: this goes in your `PreferenceActivity` that you used to create the preference view