# change volume from PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, volume, preferenceactivity

i have a problem regarding changing the volume for Ringer, Notification etc, from PreferenceActivity.

My pref.xml look like this for volume:

```
    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Incoming Call">

    <RingtonePreference
            android:name="Ringtone Preference"
            android:summary="Select a ringtone"
            android:title="Ringtones"
            android:key="ringtonePref" />
    <VolumePreference
        android:name="Volume Preference"
        android:summary="Ringtone Volume"
        android:title="Ringtone Volume"
        android:key="ringVolPref"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

and i don;t know how can i change the volume for ringtone (for notification volume i've declared another PreferenceCategory.) .

This is the code for PreferenceActivity:

```
public class SettingTest extends PreferenceActivity implements onPreferenceClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.ringtone);

        RingtonePreference ringVolPref = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("ringVolPref");
        RingtonePreference notifVolPref = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("notifVolPref");

    public boolean  onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
        int progress = 1;
        if (preference.getKey().equals("ringVolPref")){

            AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);


        }
        return true;

      }
```

and i dont know how to put the code in onPreferenceClic(). 
Please help guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement `onPreferenceClickListener` in your class then on the `onPreferenceClick` method you override use the key you set in your xml to find what one was clicked

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518667/best-way-to-update-checkbox-prefefences/10519018#10519018) for similar example

Comment: in PreferenceActivity i have: 
`ringVolPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                 //*code
            return false;
        }
    }); `
where is placed the //* code, i don't know how to put the code with same functionality like in above code (with a seekBar declared from Activity)

Comment: i saw the example, but i cannot figure how to implement on <VolumePreference

Comment: please see my Edited Code above. In onPreferenceClick body, i think it's the wrong code, because the volume still don't change